Does it make sense to ask for the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{x}\cos(e^x)$?
Of course, in $L^1$ it doesn't make any sense since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|\text{d}x$ diverges, so we could throw away the "usual" definition: $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx$$ But, in the sense of tempered distributions it does. Following the link, we can see that in fact $T=e^{x}\cos(e^x)$ is a tempered distribution so we could ask for the Fourier transform of such function. Working a little we see$$\widehat{e^{x}\cos(e^x)}=\widehat{\sin(e^x)'}=(2\pi i\xi)\widehat{\sin(e^x)}$$
have I done everything correctly? How can I compute $\widehat{\sin(e^x)}$?

While T may not be a tempered distribution it certainly is the derivative of one. The substitution $e^x=t$ transforms the Fourier transform into a Mellin transform.

@CrackedBauxite why? What about the link I shared?

@NinadMunshi The derivative of which is $\sin(e^x)$ right? So I have to see if such distribution is tempered?

While $T$ is not tempered distribution it certainly is the derivative of one as you noted. So let's compute the Fourier transform of $\sin(e^x)$
$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\sin(e^x)\right\}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(e^x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}e^{-2\pi i\log (t) \xi}dt$$
$$ = \int_0^\infty \sin(t)t^{(-2\pi i\xi)-1}dt = \mathcal{M}\left\{\sin(t)\right\}(s=-2\pi i\xi)$$
where we recognize the last integral as the Mellin transform of $\sin(t)$ which is
$$= -\sin\left(i \pi^2\xi\right)\Gamma\left(-2\pi i \xi\right)$$
Applying the derivative property gives us
$$\hat{T} = -2\pi \xi\sinh\left(\pi^2\xi\right)\Gamma(-2\pi i \xi)$$

Where did the $\log t$ term go?

$e^{\log(t)}= ...$

The space of tempered distributions is stable by differentiation. Since $\sin(e^x)$ is bounded and so a tempered distribution, it follows that $T$ is also a tempered distribution. Your confusion might come from the "growth like $e^x$" which is not common for such distributions, but not sufficient to characterize them ...

@LL3.14 that is incorrect, just observe the domain of this distribution. It is not continuous on Schwartz space, $T\left(\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{2}\right)\right)$ is unbounded.

But $e^{-|x|}$ is not a Schwartz function ... and on the other hand, if $T$ is a tempered distribution, and $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function, then
$$
|\langle T',\varphi\rangle| = |\langle T,\varphi'\rangle|
$$
is finite because $\varphi'$ is a Schwartz function, right ?

And actually no, $\langle T,e^{-|x|/2}\rangle$ is finite because by integration by parts
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{x/2} \cos(e^x),\mathrm d x = C - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-x/2}\sin(e^x),\mathrm d y
$$
